# Using AWK to combine files

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a folder with 179 tab-separated text files. They all have the same format. Here's a link to sample data:

http://www.mvabl.com/public/sample_data.txt

(This sample has the 5 headers, 5 lines of data I want, and all of the trailing data that I do **not** want.)

I want to strip the first four header lines completely, then use the fifth as the header for all rows in a single file that combines the data - WITHOUT the trailing data.

I also want to append two fields: a filename field, and one for the value of Prelim 4. So the output would look like:

```
Filename    Curr    Storefront Name Identifier  M-Type  Quantity    Net Amt Net Amt Total   Code    Title   Item    A-Type  B-Type  Vendor_ID   Offline Indicator   company donotuse
file1   ZAR ZA  44056971    Family Monthly PAID 1   .061038 .061038 US3E40400141    subtitle1   person  1   1   US3E40400141    1   BlueMelon   
file2   ZAR ZA  44056975    Family Monthly PAID 1   .061038 .061038 US3E40400142    subtitle2   person2 1   1   US3E40400142    1   BlueMelon   
file3   ZAR ZA  44057007    Family Monthly PAID 1   .061038 .061038 US3E40400144    subtitle3   person3 1   1   US3E40400144    1   BlueMelon   
...
file179 ZAR ZA  44057330    Family Monthly PAID 1   .061038 .061038 US3E40400107    subtitle5   person5 1   1   US3E40400107    1   BlueMelon
```

I'm a COMPLETE noobie to shell scripting. Literally 1 week of experience.

To add the first field, I've gotten this far, and am stuck:

```
gawk 'NR==5;FNR>5 {print FILENAME,"\t",$0} /Row/ {f=0; nextfile} f' *.txt > result.txt
```

I have no idea how to add the second field (the value of Prelim Data 4).

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: An example would make it much easier to understand what you want to do. Please post mock data and the output you'd like to obtain from it.

Comment: "I also want to append two fields: a filename field, and one for the value of Prelim 4" But "Prelim 4" is supposed to have two fields...

Comment: I just added a link to sample/mockup data. http://www.mvabl.com/public/sample_data.txt

Also, Hauke, thank you. I wasn't clear. the "two fields" in Prelim 1-4 are key-value pairs. So I want to keep the **value** from Prelim4. Should be clearer if you look at the mockup data I just linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you appear to have GNU awk, how about

```
gawk '
  /^Row Count/ {nextfile} 
  NR == 5 {$0 = "Filename" OFS $0; print} 
  FNR > 5 {$0 =  FILENAME  OFS $0; print}
' OFS='\t' *.txt
```

Comment: Yup, that worked! Thanks, steel driver. I tried to +1 you, but I don't have enough points to have it show up publicly.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR == 4 { pd4=$2; };
     NR == 5 { print $0 " FILENAME PD4";};
     FNR == 6 { print $0 " " FILENAME " " pd4; nextfile; }' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thanks Hauke! Would you be able to explain the FNR == 7? Should that be FNR == 6?

Comment: `NR` is counting through all files. `FNR` is reset for every new file. In your first example the data was in line 7.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can strip out the "trailing data"? In each file, that section starts with a row whose first field is "Row Count". I don't want that data.

Comment: @Steve My code should not have output anything after the 6th/7th line. But I have added a command to explicitly skip the rest of the file.